# Getting a Joomla 4 API component to work with language files

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-api, language

When programming a component for an API, the config contains the following language file definitions:

```
<api>
    <files folder="api">
        <folder>src</folder>
    </files>
    <languages folder="api">
        <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/com_mycomponent.ini</language>
        <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/com_mycomponent.sys.ini</language>
    </languages>
</api>
```

The component installs without errors, but the language files in the folder /api/language/en-GB/* of the component aren't copied to the folder /api/language/en-GB/ as described here https://www.dionysopoulos.me/book/com-lang.html.

When I copy the language files manually, they are interpreted correctly.
Languages other than en-GB do not seem to work.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's a bug. You should report it to developers.

Comment: Thanks: I reported the bug https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/41944

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the language files with the API rather than loading the language files into the shared `\language` directories you can use the simpler version of the elements in the manifest file.

Place your language files in your `api\com_mycomponent\language` the source folder and include the file in the `com_mycomponent.zip`.

In your `mycomponent.xml` you need to include the language folder in the `<api>` element to instruct it to be copied from the com_mycomponent.zip to the `..\api\com_mycomponent\language` directory of the Joomla instance.

```
<api>
    <files folder="api">
        <folder>src</folder>
        <folder>language</folder>
    </files>
</api>
```

If you would like to place the language files in the shared language directory, `\api\language`, then the folder attribute of your language element needs to the reflect the location of the language folder inside the `com_mycomponent.zip`, where the language files are to be copied from.

```
<api>
...
    <languages folder="\location\in\zip">
        <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/com_mycomponent.ini</language>
        <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/com_mycomponent.sys.ini</language>
    </languages>
</api>
```

If you use the second approach then you don't need the `<folder>language</folder> in the <files>` element

Comment: Thanks Irata. For the 2nd approach it should say "If you would like to place the language files in the shared language directory, \api\language ... " and the <languages> folder should remain under the <api> element within the config file?

Comment: I have updated the answer to correct folder name and made the location of the language element clearer as per your question.